# Use Redmine REST API for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, authentication, redmine

I am working on a service which requires authentication.

I would like to base the authentication on my Redmine and grant access to registered users which are members in a private project.

The membership I have figured out:

```
curl -v -u account:secret \
https://myredmine/projects/private/memberships.json
```

But how to find out if a user can authenticate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/users/current.json`:

```
curl -v -u account:secret \
https://myredmine/users/current.json
```

It will return 401 if the user fails to login.

Add `?include=memberships` to the URL to retrieve a list of associated projects.

I don't think it will work with OpenID though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in API. You can enable it for each user, once you get the key:

```
// Pseudo-code
api_key = '65454ftfg53543f34g34f23g'
url = "http://www.myredminesite.com/projects/my_project/issues.json?key=" + api_key
```

You can enable the API key if you log in and click on "My Account", then on the right should be your API access key.project.

There where some issues with older version I think. I run **Redmine 2.1.2.stable** and that works great.